# push method is not working with javascript if else shorthand

Tags: javascript

I have list of Array, I filtered it to an object based on category. Initially I have used shorthand expression of if else which was giving error but the function is working fine with general if else condition. I am not able to figure our what cause issue with shorthand expression. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scm9uh8g/)

```
var a =[[{'cat':'student','renk':1},{'cat':'student','renk':2},{'cat':'student','renk':10}],[{'cat':'teacher','renk':1},{'cat':'teacher','renk':2}]]

var obj = {}

for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
for(var z =0;z<a[i].length;z++){
obj[a[i][z]['cat']]
if(obj[a[i][z]['cat']]){
obj[a[i][z]['cat']].push(a[i][z])
}
else{
obj[a[i][z]['cat']] = [a[i][z]]
}

//obj[a[i][z]['cat']] =  obj[a[i][z]['cat']]?obj[a[i][z]['cat']].push(a[i][z]):[a[i][z]]
}
}
console.log(obj)
```

And please suggest if there is any better way to get this job done

Comment: yes, it seems like horrible :)

Comment: @PatrickEvans the ternary line is at the bottom commented out

Comment: just remove assignment

Comment: I can't follow this catastrophe, how about storing `obj[a[i][z]['cat']]` into a var?

Comment: why not https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ujg63nay/3/?

Comment: or https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ujg63nay/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you really need to do all this, from your sample each sub array in the `a` array belongs to the same category so you could do something like

```js
var a = [
  [{
    'cat': 'student',
    'renk': 1
  }, {
    'cat': 'student',
    'renk': 2
  }, {
    'cat': 'student',
    'renk': 10
  }],
  [{
    'cat': 'teacher',
    'renk': 1
  }, {
    'cat': 'teacher',
    'renk': 2
  }]
]

var obj = {}

a.forEach(function(array) {
  if (array.length) {
    obj[array[0].cat] = array; //use array.slice(0) if you want to have a copy of the array
  }
})
op.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2)
```

```html
<pre id="op"></pre>
```

---

But if you are not sure about it and want to use ternary operator then

```js
var a = [
  [{
    'cat': 'student',
    'renk': 1
  }, {
    'cat': 'student',
    'renk': 2
  }, {
    'cat': 'student',
    'renk': 10
  }],
  [{
    'cat': 'teacher',
    'renk': 1
  }, {
    'cat': 'teacher',
    'renk': 2
  }]
]

var obj = {}

a.forEach(function(array) {
  if (array.length) {
    array.forEach(function(rec) {
      obj[rec.cat] ? obj[rec.cat].push(rec) : obj[rec.cat] = [rec]
    })
  }
})
op.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2)
```

```html
<pre id="op"></pre>
```

Comment: You don't need ` if (array.length) {` for the `forEach` simply won't execute if length is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want :

```
var a =[[{'cat':'student','renk':1},{'cat':'student','renk':2},{'cat':'student','renk':10}],[{'cat':'teacher','renk':1},{'cat':'teacher','renk':2}]];

var obj = {};

for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
  for(var z=0; z<a[i].length; z++) {
    //obj[a[i][z]['cat']]  //I have commented this as its not needed
    if(obj[a[i][z]['cat']]) {
      obj[a[i][z]['cat']].push(a[i][z]);
    }
    else {
      obj[a[i][z]['cat']] = [a[i][z]];
    }
    //obj[a[i][z]['cat']] =  obj[a[i][z]['cat']]?obj[a[i][z]['cat']].push(a[i][z]):[a[i][z]]
  }
}
console.log(obj);
```